# A strategy to build iteratively tables for fitted models statistics with sjPlot

Tags: r, datatable, model, sjplot

I'm facing with this fitted models list:

```
    Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: value ~ COND + (1 | ID)
   Data: .

REML criterion at convergence: 389.4

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.71940 -0.52142 -0.02861  0.43071  2.17384 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 14.461   3.803   
 Residual              5.527   2.351   
Number of obs: 75, groups:  ID, 25

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -1.5888     0.8942 35.1754  -1.777   0.0842 .
CONDNEG-NOC   0.1964     0.6649 48.0000   0.295   0.7690  
CONDNEU-NOC   0.1130     0.6649 48.0000   0.170   0.8658  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CONDNEG
CONDNEG-NOC -0.372        
CONDNEU-NOC -0.372  0.500
```

**and other 12 elements, all embedded into an object called `model_list`**

If I would like to present them as into an elegant tables (as it is shown singularly for each model here in these slides) with sjPlot() package or others (alternatively):

[image]

Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: You should try `tab_model(model_list, show.ci =  FALSE, show.se =  TRUE)`

Comment: It turns back this error `> tab_model(models_list_2, show.ci =  FALSE, show.se =  TRUE)
Error in if (fam.info$is_linear) transform <- NULL else transform <- "exp" : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
Could not access model information`.

Comment: Actually in this object are contained twelwe models outcomes

Comment: I don't know whether this code could fit a table a model by one

Comment: Yes there are 12 models. You did indicate that in the question. What  if you try doing `tab_model(models_list[[1]])` what is the error.

Comment: I got the same error :-(

Comment: What type of models do you have? How did you fit them?

Comment: I've tried to fit them both with the method of the previous post as well as via another method: `models_list_2 <- out_long %>%
  group_by(signals) %>%
  do(fit = lmerTest::lmer(value ~ COND + (1|ID), data = .)) %>% 
  pull(fit) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x) summary(x)) %>% 
  setNames(sort(unique(out_long$signals)))`

Comment: as you could see they have been fitted via lmer()

Comment: just use `models_list_3 <- out_long %>%   group_by(signals) %>%   do(fit = lmerTest::lmer(value ~ COND + (1|ID), data = .)) %>%    pull(fit)`. Now do `tab_model(model_list_3, show.ci =  FALSE, show.se =  TRUE)`

Comment: It worked good. But if you do not mind I would rather prefer to get a singular table for each model

Comment: So I think this would require the employment of some iterative functions like for loops, map() and other. I do not know how to set them out

Comment: But the image provided in the question is just one image with all the models. Anyway to get each table, use lapply(model_list, tab_model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using summary of the models rather than the models themselves. Do:

```
models_list_3 <- out_long %>%   
       group_by(signals) %>%   
       do(fit = lmerTest::lmer(value ~ COND + (1|ID), data = .)) %>%    
       pull(fit) 

tab_model(model_list_3, show.ci =  FALSE, show.se =  TRUE)
```

for each model separately, you could do:

```
 lapply(model_list_3, tab_model, show.ci = FALSE, show.se = TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry. To that statistics I'm interested in reporting I will edit my post

Comment: Even though I've trying setting the df = T (while as far as the Pr(<t) I have no clue how to show it off), I'm not able to get those values.

Comment: @mały_statystyczny use `show.p = FALSE, show.df =  FALSE`  etc

Comment: Ok. So fro showing them off that would be set out as TRUE. And as far as the P(>|t|) statistics??

Comment: @mały_statystyczny to NOT show them, you set it to FALSE, to SHOW them, you set it to TRUE

Comment: Ok fine. There is a difference I'm noticing. The degrees of freedom into the tables are always 70, which are pretty different from the value you could see into the statistics I reported

Comment: @mały_statystyczny I am not quite sure how to handle that. Although I do believe the answer given here, covers prety much what the question intended. Am sorry

Comment: Do not worry, maybe I got the way how to handle with it